# EF Core, Sqlite, InMemory, Code First - just HOW?

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I want to create a database with structure from my test model.
In memory. Using Sqlite and Entity Framework Core.
Of course, code first.
I created my model.

`Data\DataContext.cs:`

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace MyTest.Data {

    public class DataContext : DbContext {

        public DbSet<Record> Records { get; set; }

        public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

    }

}
```

`Data\Record.cs:`

```cs
using System;

namespace MyTest.Data {

    public class Record {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    }
}
```

And I have this test code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Data.Common;
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

using MyTest.Data;

namespace MyTest {
    
    public class Startup {
        
        static DbConnection TestDbConnection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=:memory:;Cache=shared");

        void InitializeTestDatabase() {
            var dbOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder().UseSqlite(TestDbConnection).Options;
            var dbContext = new DataContext(dbOptions);
            dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
                var testString = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                dbContext.Records.Add(new Record { Name = testString.Substring(0, 8), Description = testString, Time = DateTime.Now });
            }
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

    }

}
```

Of course it throws SQL exception, because there is no such table like "Records". Obviously. The structure was normally created with migrations, but I've read you cannot use migrations with `InMemory`. That I should use `EnsureCreated()` instead. But then how can I get the structure built from my models code? What am I missing here?

Comment: Why do you need to use InMemory? in-mem isn't supposed to be an enduring database, so it doesn't make sense to use migrations, which are a device for evolving a production database in a sane and time-scrollable way, over time. I believe EnsureCreated should create an db that is compatible with the model and (because it also doesn't create a db that functions migrationally) is aligned with the goals of in-mem, but I'm not sure that in-mem is what you'll ultimately want to do. As such you should perhaps look to create a db normally, on disk, using migrations(more design time than run time thing)

Comment: @CaiusJard I just want to create a test table. Dummy table in dummy database for test, but I want to make it as simple as possible (zero configuration / dependencies / paths / file references). Also, Code First - so I don't want to write SQL or create database structure otherwise - EF can do that for me, can't it? All I care is to have a table with data. Created each time the app starts. I don't want files, I don't want creating table manually.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've needed to add `SqliteConnection.Open` call on my connection to make it work:

```
var conn = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
conn.Open(); // open connection to use

var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<VegaDbContext>()
   .UseSqlite(conn)
   .Options;

using (var ctx = new VegaDbContext(options))
{
    ctx.Database.EnsureCreated();
    ctx.Records.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Amazing, the error message I was getting was misleading then. It said I had no table `Records`, but opening the connection before using it in my data context solved the issue. I was skeptical about the idea, but I tested it and it really works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Harry was glad to help! I had the same table and the same issue)

Comment: It's documented, just someone has to read it - [Using SQLite in-memory databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/sqlite#using-sqlite-in-memory-databases).

Comment: @IvanStoev I read it first, but I forgot about opening the connection anyway. My bad. What is happening there? Does `EnsureCreated()` create the database structure if the connection is opened and silently skips that when it's closed? I'm just curious.

Comment: `EnsureCreated` relies on two abstract methods `bool Exists()` and `bool HasTables()`. They are implemented by every database provider. The Sqlite implementation is in class called `SqliteDatabaseCreator` which you can find in EF Core GitHub repo. The `Exists` method starts with `if (connectionStringBuilder.DataSource.Equals(":memory:", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || connectionStringBuilder.Mode == SqliteOpenMode.Memory) return true;` :-)