# How can I create a new SQLite database at runtime using ASP.NET Core & EF Core?

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a large SQL Server database. Imagine the devices that this database receives and sends data from.

In order for the devices to continue working in an offline scenario, I want to create unique SQLite databases for each of them. When I send a request to the relevant endpoint, I want a new SQLite database to be created based on a `DbContext` object I specify from scratch.

This database should be populated with data specific to only that device from the main database. After the request is complete, I want to return this database, and then I want the file created with the name `deneme.db` for this instance to be deleted from the backend directory.

In other words, a new database file will be created every time a request is made. These databases will be specific to devices, and the number of these devices may increase in the future. Therefore, there will be no fixed databases.

I want to do these operations using ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core, but I couldn't find any resources. Can you help?

Comment: AFAIK if you create and initialize (via `Database.Migrate` or `Database.EnsureCreated`) a SQLite db context with filename which does not exist - EF Core will automatically create the databse.

Comment: I'm doing this, but when I try to convert the file to binary after creating it, it tells me that the file is already in use. Even if I perform the file creation within a "using" block, I still encounter this error.

Comment: Then try managing connection "directly", like done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64012860/2501279) for in-memory one. EF and ADO.NET have some connection pooling mechanism which can prevent the file from being accessible right away. Alternatively if this doesn't work - move the db manipulation to separate process.

Comment: [link](https://pastebin.pl/view/1e341c6f) this is my code. But I get this error: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\erhaa\source\repos\RuntimeSQLite\RuntimeSQLite\Databases\test.db' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: As to my experience, sqlite has some *unexpected features* (crude people would call this *bugs*). One of those is that a connection stays open not only after insert and update, but also after select (simple select, not only for BLOBs). I had a hell of a trouble closing all remaining transactions, and getting rid of an "ATTACH"ed DB is still something I cannot manage.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for a database, like SQLite, which is contained within a single ".db" file and can easily be moved to different clients, without encountering the mentioned problem?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your requirement you could try below code:

service:

```
public class SQLiteDbService
{
    private readonly YourMainDbContext _mainDbContext;
    
    public SQLiteDbService(YourMainDbContext mainDbContext)
    {
        _mainDbContext = mainDbContext;
    }
    
    public async Task<string> CreateAndPopulateSQLiteDb(string deviceId)
    {
        var sqliteConnectionString = $"Data Source={deviceId}.db";
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<YourSQLiteDbContext>()
            .UseSqlite(sqliteConnectionString)
            .Options;

        await using var sqliteDbContext = new YourSQLiteDbContext(options);
        await sqliteDbContext.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();
        
        var deviceData = _mainDbContext.Devices
            .Where(d => d.DeviceId == deviceId)
            .Include(/* include related data as necessary */)
            .FirstOrDefault();
        
        if (deviceData == null) throw new Exception("Device not found");
        
        sqliteDbContext.Devices.Add(deviceData);
        await sqliteDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        
        return sqliteConnectionString;
    }
    
    public async Task DeleteSQLiteDbFile(string connectionString)
    {
        var dbFilePath = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString).DataSource;
        if (File.Exists(dbFilePath))
        {
            File.Delete(dbFilePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class DeviceController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly SQLiteDbService _sqliteDbService;

    public DeviceController(SQLiteDbService sqliteDbService)
    {
        _sqliteDbService = sqliteDbService;
    }

    [HttpGet("getDeviceData/{deviceId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetDeviceData(string deviceId)
    {
        try
        {
            var sqliteConnectionString = await _sqliteDbService.CreateAndPopulateSQLiteDb(deviceId);
            
            var dbFilePath = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder(sqliteConnectionString).DataSource;
            var dbFileBytes = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(dbFilePath);
            var fileResult = new FileContentResult(dbFileBytes, "application/octet-stream")
            {
                FileDownloadName = "demofile.db"
            };

            await _sqliteDbService.DeleteSQLiteDbFile(sqliteConnectionString);

            return fileResult;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    .......
    services.AddDbContext<YourMainDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("connection string"));
    services.AddScoped<SQLiteDbService>();
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Have you tried it? Is this code working for you?